Unable to Add Tags to Files in Windows: Missing "Tags" Property in Details Tab
Following this Tweet, I'm trying to organize my files by adding tags in Windows, as outlined in these instructions. However, I've encountered an issue where the "Tags" property does not appear in the "Details" tab of the file's Properties window. None of the properties in the "Details" tab seem editable.

               

I have followed the steps described in the article, but the expected "Tags" field is absent. This issue persists across different file types and folders.
Can anyone explain why this might be happening and how to enable tagging? Are there specific file types or system settings that support this feature?
P.S. Bounouse question, a follow-up to this other question: Is there a way to show the tags in the "Navigation pane" like Files does?

Does this apply? Not all files stored in Windows can be tagged. Tagging is only supported on images, documents, and videos. And, in some cases, even some supported file types may not allow tagging.

@MichaelHarvey, aha, so I do see the tags for images. So I think it is safe to say, that Windows File Explorer doesn't have a full fledged tagging functionality. Right?

That is correct.

Though Windows Explorer does not provide an interface to add a tag for Page Description Format (PDF) and some other file types, those tags can be added, and they can be found in Explorer, like any other tag.
For example, free version of PDF-XChange Editor enables adding tags ("keywords") through the document property dialog. Here, I've inserted, Added_Superuser_tag, and then saved the changed document.

Opening Explorer and searching on tag:super finds the tagged document (no wild-cards needed). Also, pressing Windows and typing added_superuser in the Search box quickly finds that document, once indexing has been completed.

Explorer's Search also turns up that document using keyword:super and tags:super (plural). Obviously, MS has gone to considerable effort to implement searching on attributes, but not so much on modifying those extended attributes for all file types.
Note that there are various tools to modify ordinary and extended file attributes such as tag, e.g., Mp3tag and alternatives, DeClutter: File Tagger and Organizer, ExifTool and alternatives, etc.

Interesting. So, the "Tags" property still exists for other file types, even though File Explorer doesn't allow us to see/change them. At the moment, I am experimenting with  Files and TagSpaces to see if they can be a good substitute for the File Explorer.

It might be that Explorer Search is doing a bit of interpretation: the field name might be "keywords", but Search also finds it when "tag" or "tags" is entered.

By the way, how did you get to the above "Document Properties" dialog?  Mine is not editable and certainly does not have the above shape and look.

In Sumatra PDF Reader. If yours is not editable, the PDF file may be locked.

Locked by what? like being used by another program?  How can I unlock it then?

Are you sure this is Sumatra PDF? Because mine too doesn't look like this and there is no keywords cell, and no editable cells at all for that matter.

@Foad, Sjotroll: Please accept my apologies! The wrong tool was referenced; free version of PDF-XChange Editor was used to add tags. The answer has been modified accordingly. [Both Sumatra PDF Reader and PDF-XChange Editor are excellent tools, and I use both frequently. Sumatra is quicker and can read .epub and other files, whereas XChange can edit PDF's.]

@Foad, a PDF can be made secured, i.e., read-only, effectively locking it from editing. For example, some government forms are displayed in PDF-XChange Editor as <title> [SECURED], meaning not editable. (However, that locked document could be printed as PDF, and that copy is editable.)
